# Creating custom writer and reader in Golang

Tags: go

I'm new to golang (wrangling it for a week or so). At this point, I'm porting a library from PHP to Golang since I felt like I should move this to a language that is way more efficient especially when doing low-level stuff.

In PHP, manual serialization is done by opening a filehandle first.

```
public function __construct($filename, $mode='r+b')
{
    some checking and stuff...

    $this->_fileHandle = @fopen($filename, $mode);

}

public function seek($offset, $whence=SEEK_SET)
{
    return fseek($this->_fileHandle, $offset, $whence);
}

public function readInt()
{
    $str = $this->_fread(4);

    return  ord($str[0]) << 24 |
            ord($str[1]) << 16 |
            ord($str[2]) << 8  |
            ord($str[3]);
}

public function readLong()
{ ....... }

public function writeInt($value)
{
    settype($value, 'integer');
    $this->_fwrite( chr($value>>24 & 0xFF) .
                    chr($value>>16 & 0xFF) .
                    chr($value>>8  & 0xFF) .
                    chr($value     & 0xFF),   4  );
}

public function writeLong($value)
{ ..... }

protected function _fwrite($data, $length=null)
{
    if ($length === null ) {
        fwrite($this->_fileHandle, $data);
    } else {
        fwrite($this->_fileHandle, $data, $length);
    }
}

protected function _fread($length=1)
{
    if ($length == 0) {
        return '';
    }

    if ($length < 1024) {
        return fread($this->_fileHandle, $length);
    }

    $data = '';
    while ( $length > 0 && ($nextBlock = fread($this->_fileHandle, $length)) != false ) {
        $data .= $nextBlock;
        $length -= strlen($nextBlock);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Everything pretty much revolves around the fileHandle.

In Golang, I understood that os.File can be wrapped in a custom reader and writer (io.Reader and io.Writer) which is fine until I needed to move offsets (using seek in php) and replacing some bytes.

```
type FileSystem struct {
    FileHandle      *os.File
    byte        []byte
    Pos   int64
}

func NewFileSystem(filepath string, create bool) (*FileSystem, error) {

    var file *os.File
    var err error

    if create == false {
        if _, err_r := os.Stat(filepath); os.IsNotExist(err_r) {
            return nil, err_r
        }
        file, err = os.OpenFile(filepath, os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    } else {
        file, err = os.Create(filepath)
    }

        if err != nil { 
            os.Exit(0)
            return nil, err
        }

        fileinfo, err := file.Stat()
        if err != nil {
          return nil, err
        }
        filesize := fileinfo.Size()
        text := make([]byte, filesize)

        if create == false {
            file.Read(text)
        }

        return &FileSystem{
            FileHandle: file,
            byte: text,
            Pos: 0,
        }, nil

}

func (fs *FileSystem) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (int64, error) {

   var newoffset int64
   switch whence {
   case 0:
       newoffset = offset
   case 1:
       newoffset = fs.Pos + offset
   case 2:
       newoffset = int64(len(fs.byte)) - offset
   }

   if newoffset == fs.Pos {
       return newoffset, nil
   }

   fs.Pos = newoffset
   return fs.Pos, nil
}

func (fs *FileSystem) ReadByte() (b byte, err error) {
    fs.Pos++
    return fs.byte[fs.Pos-1], nil
}

func (fs *FileSystem) ReadInt() (n int32, err error) {
   fs.Pos += 4
   return (int32(fs.byte[fs.Pos-4]) << 24) | (int32(fs.byte[fs.Pos-3]) << 16) |
    (int32(fs.byte[fs.Pos-2]) << 8) | int32(fs.byte[fs.Pos-1]), nil
}

func (fs *FileSystem) ReadLong() (n int64, err error) {
   i1, _ := fs.ReadInt()
   i2, _ := fs.ReadInt()
   return (int64(i1) << 32) | int64(i2), nil
}

func (fs *FileSystem) WriteByte(b byte) error {

    w := bufio.NewWriter(fs.FileHandle)
    if (len(fs.byte) <= 0) {
        fs.byte = append(fs.byte, b)
    } else {
        fs.byte[fs.Pos] = b
    }

    err := w.WriteByte(b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Error writing data: ", err)
    }

    w.Flush()
    fs.Pos++
    return nil
}

func (fs *FileSystem) WriteInt(i int32) error {

    err := fs.WriteByte(byte(i >> 24))
    if err == nil {
        err = fs.WriteByte(byte(i >> 16))
        if err == nil {
            err = fs.WriteByte(byte(i >> 8))
            if err == nil {
                err = fs.WriteByte(byte(i))
            }
        }
    }
    return err
}

func (fs *FileSystem) WriteLong(i int64) error {
    err := fs.WriteInt(int32(i >> 32))
    if err == nil {
        err = fs.WriteInt(int32(i))
    }
    return err
}
```

Which doesn't actually replace the byte when I do, Seek(12, 0) and WriteInt/WriteLong, etc.. (because WriteByte() pretty much writes at the end of file always..and yes the sample above actually gives out error when index is out of range, especially for new file (length is 0)).

I'm wondering if there is something (other than WriteByte()) that takes offset as argument to overwrite the byte at that offset.

Comment: don't post the whole code like that, Say what you were trying to achieve in shortest possible example, Try to explain in words, as it is not possible to understand from PHP code.

Comment: I think you are looking for this, `*os.File`  have methods `f.ReadAt()` and `f.WriteAt()`, which can also be used by multiple go-routines.

Comment: "In Golang, I understood that os.File can be wrapped in a custom reader and writer". No! Do not think like that. A os.File is a thing with a lot of methods so you can do a lot with an os.File. Sometimes a function just wants to do one task, e.g read from a thing. Then you do not need all the fancy os.File methods an a simple os.Reader is enough which allows reading (and nothing else). You can pass a os.File to someone needing just an os.Reader but thats not wrapping.

Comment: @Volker: `os.Reader` should be `io.Reader`.

Comment: What Volker said. Make your code depend on one of the interfaces in the io package, such as [Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), [ReadSeeker](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadSeeker), [WriterAt](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriterAt), etc. (pick the smallest interface that works for any given function, most often simply io.Reader and io.Writer). Then replace os.File with something like [bytes.Buffer](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer), [bytes.Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Reader) in tests and such.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into writeAt/readAt, I may also have to rewrite it and deal with writing []byte at offset instead of byte..

Comment: Also, it looks like directly doing it on files not only places stress on disk, but also slows down I/O (if I'll be doing a whole lot of it on some 1000+ files) and is resource intensive, so I may have to buffer it before actually flushing it on disk..

Comment: I advise you to write in a buffer and write the buffer in a file when you have finished manipulating it. Assuming you have enough memory and you are not handling very big files.